# Movie where in the end, a guy has to manually detonate a nuclear bomb to destroy aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I watched this movie a loooong time ago, but can't seem to find it on the internet.

The main plot involves these soldiers/mercenaries who land on an asteroid/meteor/moon or something similar, but I don't remember why they go there. Anyways, they end up crash landing (I think), and the survivors must find a place to stay safe from the harsh weather or something. But, they end up finding this flying snake/eel alien lifeform who travel in big packs and eat up any one close enough.

Desperate, the survivors decide to run back to their crashed ship to get their weapons. They end up getting away, but one man is crazy and end up shooting some of the survivors to distract the aliens. While running away, they find a band of smugglers (I think they were smugglers) who have also crash landed.

I'm not sure what happens after this, but I know they kill most of the smugglers except one, and this one surviving smugglers is special because he knows how to fly the ships.

Towards the end of the movie, they decide to detonate a nuclear bomb that was hidden on the soldier/mercenary ship by using a remote device so that they could destroy the aliens or asteroid. However, the harsh weather conditions breaks the antenna or the crazy mercenary breaks something in the ship, I can't remember, but one of the main protagonists ends up having to manually set the bomb off, dying in the process so that his friends could escape.

I'm trying to be really specific with the details here, but I might be off or wrong with some details. I also know that the place they landed on was very rocky/sharp hills and cliffs, with many caves as well.

I know it's not *"Without Warning", "Armageddon", "Deep Impact"*, because the movie takes place in the future with 'power armor' and other future tech, and most of the setting takes place on the asteroid/meteor/moon.

This movie might be tough to find since I doubt it was very popular, but for some odd reason I can not get some of the scenes from the movie out of my head, nor can I say what the exact sequence of events of the movie was.

Comment: Bits of this sound like Pitch Black.

Comment: How long ago was loooooong?

Comment: This sounds a lot like Halo: Nightfall but this was out in 2014

Comment: Holy Cow it is Halo: Nightfall!! I could have sworn I watched this movie like around 2010ish, but I guess I was wrong on that part too. I should have known it would be Halo related, reading some lore from Halo 5 is what triggerred the random scenes in my mind. Thank you Bosc! Also, oops this whole time I thought the movie was on and asteroid-like body.

Comment: @Mayman feel free to write an answer yourself and accept it, so this question is closed :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Halo: Nightfall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3804114/). The scene with the manually-armed explosive is right at the end of [episode 5 (of 5)](http://dai.ly/x2d02p5).

[image]